# No Post Data (bitpay)

Tags: php

We are integrating Bitpay to our website but each time we make payment and call back out notification url we keep getting "no post data". Our url is https as requested and everything seem to be fine please help. this is the code.

**bp_options.php**

```
global $bpOptions;
$bpOptions['apiKey'] = 'xxxxxxx';
$bpOptions['verifyPos'] = true;
$bpOptions['notificationEmail'] = 'our email';
$bpOptions['notificationURL'] = 'https://www.ourwebsite.com/completesubscription/bitpaynotification';;
$bpOptions['redirectURL'] = 'https://www.ourwebsite.com/completesubscription?method=bitpay';;
$bpOptions['currency'] = 'USD';
$bpOptions['physical'] = true;
$bpOptions['fullNotifications'] = true;
$bpOptions['transactionSpeed'] = 'high';
$bpOptions['logFile'] = '/bplog.txt';
$bpOptions['useLogging'] = TRUE;
```

**bp_lib.php**

```
require_once 'bp_options.php';

function bpLog($contents) { 
   global $bpOptions; 

   try { 
     if(isset($bpOptions['logFile']) && $bpOptions['logFile'] != '') { 
         $file = dirname(__FILE__).$bpOptions['logFile']; 
     } else { 
        // Fallback to using a default logfile name in case the variable is 
        // missing or not set. 
        $file = dirname(__FILE__).'/bplog.txt'; 
     }

     file_put_contents($file, date('m-d H:i:s').": ", FILE_APPEND);

     if (is_array($contents)) 
       $contents = var_export($contents, true); 
     else if (is_object($contents)) 
       $contents = json_encode($contents);

     file_put_contents($file, $contents."\n", FILE_APPEND);

    } catch (Exception $e) { 
      echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
    } 
}

function bpCurl($url, $apiKey, $post = false) { 
global $bpOptions;

if((isset($url) && trim($url) != '') && (isset($apiKey) && trim($apiKey) != '')) { 
try { 
$curl = curl_init(); 
$length = 0;

if ($post) { 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
$length = strlen($post); 
}

$uname = base64_encode($apiKey);

if($uname) { 
$header = array( 
'Content-Type: application/json', 
'Content-Length: ' . $length, 
'Authorization: Basic ' . $uname, 
'X-BitPay-Plugin-Info: phplib1.5', 
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 443); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ) ; 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // verify certificate 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); // check existence of CN and verify that it matches hostname 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);

$responseString = curl_exec($curl);

if($responseString == false) { 
$response = array('error' => curl_error($curl)); 
if($bpOptions['useLogging']) 
bpLog('Error: ' . curl_error($curl)); 
} else { 
$response = json_decode($responseString, true); 
if (!$response) { 
$response = array('error' => 'invalid json: '.$responseString); 
if($bpOptions['useLogging']) 
bpLog('Error - Invalid JSON: ' . $responseString); 
} 
}

curl_close($curl); 
return $response; 
} else { 
curl_close($curl); 
if($bpOptions['useLogging']) 
bpLog('Invalid data found in apiKey value passed to bpCurl. (Failed: base64_encode(apikey))'); 
return array('error' => 'Invalid data found in apiKey value passed to bpCurl. (Failed: base64_encode(apikey))'); 
} 
} catch (Exception $e) { 
@curl_close($curl); 
if($bpOptions['useLogging']) 
bpLog('Error: ' . $e->getMessage()); 
return array('error' => $e->getMessage()); 
} 
} else { 
// Invalid parameter specified 
if($bpOptions['useLogging']) 
bpLog('Error: You must supply non-empty url and apiKey parameters.'); 
return array('error' => 'You must supply non-empty url and apiKey parameters.'); 
}

}

function bpCreateInvoice($orderId, $price, $posData, $options = array()) {

global $bpOptions;

try { 
$options = array_merge($bpOptions, $options); // $options override any options found in bp_options.php 
$pos = array('posData' => $posData);

if ($bpOptions['verifyPos']) 
$pos['hash'] = bpHash(serialize($posData), $options['apiKey']);

$options['posData'] = json_encode($pos);

if(strlen($options['posData']) > 100) 
return array('error' => 'posData > 100 character limit. Are you using the posData hash?');

$options['orderID'] = $orderId; 
$options['price'] = $price;

$postOptions = array('orderID', 'itemDesc', 'itemCode', 'notificationEmail', 'notificationURL', 'redirectURL', 
'posData', 'price', 'currency', 'physical', 'fullNotifications', 'transactionSpeed', 'buyerName', 
'buyerAddress1', 'buyerAddress2', 'buyerCity', 'buyerState', 'buyerZip', 'buyerEmail', 'buyerPhone'); 

/* $postOptions = array('orderID', 'itemDesc', 'itemCode', 'notificationEmail', 'notificationURL', 'redirectURL', 
'posData', 'price', 'currency', 'physical', 'fullNotifications', 'transactionSpeed', 'buyerName', 
'buyerAddress1', 'buyerAddress2', 'buyerCity', 'buyerState', 'buyerZip', 'buyerEmail', 'buyerPhone', 
'pluginName', 'pluginVersion', 'serverInfo', 'serverVersion', 'addPluginInfo'); 
*/ 
// Usage information for support purposes. Do not modify. 
//$postOptions['pluginName'] = 'PHP Library'; 
//$postOptions['pluginVersion'] = '1.3'; 
//$postOptions['serverInfo'] = htmlentities($_SERVER['SERVER_SIGNATURE'], ENT_QUOTES);
//$postOptions['serverVersion'] = htmlentities($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], ENT_QUOTES); 
//$postOptions['addPluginInfo'] = htmlentities($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], ENT_QUOTES);

foreach($postOptions as $o) { 
if (array_key_exists($o, $options)) 
$post[$o] = $options[$o]; 
}

$post = json_encode($post);

$response = bpCurl('bitpay/api/invoice/';, $options['apiKey'], $post);

if($bpOptions['useLogging']) { 
bpLog('Create Invoice: '); 
bpLog($post); 
bpLog('Response: '); 
bpLog($response); 
}

return $response;

} catch (Exception $e) { 
if($bpOptions['useLogging']) 
bpLog('Error: ' . $e->getMessage()); 
return array('error' => $e->getMessage()); 
} 
}

function bpVerifyNotification($apiKey = false) { 
global $bpOptions;

try { 
if (!$apiKey) 
$apiKey = $bpOptions['apiKey'];

$post = file_get_contents("php://input");

if (!$post) 
return 'No post data';

$json = json_decode($post, true);

if (is_string($json)) 
return $json; // error

if (!array_key_exists('posData', $json)) 
return 'no posData';

$posData = json_decode($json['posData'], true);

if($bpOptions['verifyPos'] and $posData['hash'] != bpHash(serialize($posData['posData']), $apiKey)) 
return 'authentication failed (bad hash)';

$json['posData'] = $posData['posData'];

return $json; 
} catch (Exception $e) { 
if($bpOptions['useLogging']) 
bpLog('Error: ' . $e->getMessage()); 
return array('error' => $e->getMessage()); 
} 
}

function bpGetInvoice($invoiceId, $apiKey=false) { 
global $bpOptions;

try { 
if (!$apiKey) 
$apiKey = $bpOptions['apiKey'];

$response = bpCurl('bitpay/invoice/'.$invoiceId, $apiKey);

if (is_string($response)) 
return $response; // error

$response['posData'] = json_decode($response['posData'], true); 
$response['posData'] = $response['posData']['posData'];

return $response; 
} catch (Exception $e) { 
if($bpOptions['useLogging']) 
bpLog('Error: ' . $e->getMessage()); 
return 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
} 
}

function bpHash($data, $key) { 
global $bpOptions; 

try { 
$hmac = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $key, TRUE)); 
return strtr($hmac, array('+' => '-', '/' => '_', '=' => '')); 
} catch (Exception $e) { 
if($bpOptions['useLogging']) 
bpLog('Error: ' . $e->getMessage()); 
return 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
} 
}

function bpDecodeResponse($response) { 
global $bpOptions; 

try { 
if (empty($response) || !(is_string($response))) 
return 'Error: decodeResponse expects a string parameter.';

return json_decode($response, true); 
} catch (Exception $e) { 
if($bpOptions['useLogging']) 
bpLog('Error: ' . $e->getMessage()); 
return 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
} 
}

function bpCurrencyList() { 
global $bpOptions;

$currencies = array(); 
$rate_url = 'bitpay/rates';;

try { 
$clist = json_decode(file_get_contents($rate_url),true);

foreach($clist as $key => $value) 
$currencies[$value['code']] = $value['name'];

return $currencies; 
} catch (Exception $e) { 
if($bpOptions['useLogging']) 
bpLog('Error: ' . $e->getMessage()); 
return 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
} 
}

function bpGetRate($code = 'USD') { 
global $bpOptions;

$rate_url = 'bitpay/rates';;

try { 
$clist = json_decode(file_get_contents($rate_url),true);

foreach($clist as $key => $value) { 
if($value['code'] == $code) 
$rate = number_format($value['rate'], 2, '.', ''); 
} 

return $rate; 
} catch (Exception $e) { 
if($bpOptions['useLogging']) 
bpLog('Error: ' . $e->getMessage()); 
return 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
} 
}

send.php

$amount = $this->input->post('total_amount'); 
$id_order = $this->input->post('id_order'); 
$post_data = array( 
'notificationURL' => '/completesubscription/bitpaynotification';, 
'id_order' => $this->input->post('id_order') 
); 
$addl_options = array( 
'itemDesc' => $this->input->get('option') 
); 
$response = bpCreateInvoice($id_order, $amount, $post_data, $addl_options); 
if(!empty($response)){ 
header('Location:'.$response['url'].'');

notification.php

function BitpayNotification() 
{ 
global $bpOptions; 
$session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in'); 
echo $bpOptions['apiKey']; 
$response = bpVerifyNotification($bpOptions['apiKey']); 
$order_id = $response['posData']; 
$sessionid = $order_id; 
$this->createSubscribe($sessionid,$session_data['id']); 
}

redirect.php

$data['method'] = 'bitpay'; 
$this->load->view('complete_subscribe_view', $data);
```

Thats please check and let me know if i did anything wrong.

Comment: If you want somebody to respond, please provide a clear and concise error message or error description. In addition only include the relevant code. Don't expect people to stroll through 1k lines of code for you.

Comment: Apparently `file_get_contents("php://input");` Is not being populated. So I would start to debug from there; is it being filled or is there something wrong before....

Comment: No error message that is the problem. No only error message i am getting from my notification url is "no post data". I have check error log nothing.

Comment: What if you `var_dump` the file_get_contents(...) and start from there and figure out why this is empty/false.